# How many multisets can be made using the numbers $1$ through $n$, where each is used at most $3$ times?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Note that $n$ is a positive integer.

So we're counting multisets, except with the restriction that no multiset can have more than $3$ copies of the same elements.

The answer is $4^n$, because for each element from $1$ to $n$ you have $4$ choices: don't put that number in the multiset, put it in once, put it in twice, or put it in thrice. There is probably a much better way to explain this, if you care to then please do.

But I'm wondering whether there's a more intuitive way of thinking about this. I feel that my stumbling upon the answer $4^n$ was very much a matter of luck. Maybe it's just me that finds it unintuitive.

One of my favorite things about combinatorics is how there are so many different angles you can approach a single problem at.

**TLDR** Have you a more intuitive way of thinking of the problem?

Comment: There are $n$ choices, and $4$ ways to make each choice, so there are $4\cdot 4\cdots 4=4^n$ ways to make all the choices. I do not see how it could be any more intuitive than that.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it exactly the way you suggest.  It seems very intuitive to me, since we all know that there are $2^n$ subsets of a set with $n$ elements, by analogous reasoning.  Here's another way of looking at it, though.  If the elements are $x_1,\dots x_n$ represent the multiset with $k_i$ copies of $x_i$ by the expression $x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}\cdots x_n^{k_n}$.  Then the number of of multisets is the number of terms in the expansion of $$(1+x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3)(1+x_2+x_2^2+x_2^3)\cdots(1+x_n+x_n^2+x_n^3)$$  and there are clearly $4^n$ of these.

Comment: Actually your (much clearer) explanation indeed makes the solution seem more intuitive. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can identify every multiset with a number with $n$ digits in base $4$.

You can identify every multiset with an ordered pair of usual sets, call them high and low. If you picked $k$ in the high, that counts for twice, and if you picked it in the low, for once: example for $n=4$: $(\{1,2\},\{2,4\})\mapsto\{1,1,2,2,2,4\}$.

If some other comes to my mind, I'll write it.

Comment: YES I think this is similar to the initial idea I had before scrapping it and going with the common one, and that may be why I feel that the more obvious answer is intuitive. Thank you!